# Graphing a single row in an SSRS Line Graph

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-grouping

I have a table setup with the following columns:

```
Product Name
SalesMonth1
SalesMonth2
SalesMonth3
SalesMonth4
SalesMonth5
```

An example of a row is as follows:

```
Bread
300
600
800
900
1000
```

I am trying to put this into a line graph in SSRS but am having trouble figuring out which fields go where. In my dataset, I have a field for each "SalesMonth" column. So in my dataset, I have 6 fields total including the product name. Will this work? On which axis should the product name go and the sales fields go?

Comment: are you trying to show sales for `Bread` in each month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope your dataset uses SQL.

I would "unpivot" the data by writing a 5-part UNION SELECT, e.g.

`SELECT Product_Name , 1 AS Month , SalesMonth1 AS Sales
UNION ALL
SELECT Product_Name , 2 AS Month , SalesMonth2 AS Sales
UNION ALL
...
SELECT Product_Name , 5 AS Month , SalesMonth5 AS Sales`

Then in the SSRS Chart definition:

Month = Category Group

Product Name  = Series Group

Sales = Values

But the real real answer is that your data is probably not in a useful shape for reporting.  Will there only ever be 5 months? I suspect not...

Comment: It actually does only keep records for sales for the first 5 months of a products launch, thats all we care about. Im going to try this today. Also, they will be able to select multiple products when running the report (we do use sql). Is this going to change anything?

Comment: Just wrap the UNIONs in a derived table e.g. `SELECT * FROM ([union selects]) AS D1 WHERE Product_Name IN ( @Product_Name )`